# Present Progressive used where Present Simple should be

Tags: grammar, present-tense, present-progressive

Please look at the sentence: "In Moscow, people hurry to wherever they are going" 
This is a sentence that describes what people do on a regular basis/day to day, therefore demanding the use of the present simple. From a grammatical perspective, why therefore is the second clauses "wherever they are going", in present progressive? I understand  that the second clause can be expressed using the present simple, my question is: why is the present progressive preferred, or even 'legal', here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, but it is a tiny point. Perhaps better still would be "People in Moscow hurry to wherever they go." If I wrote it, I would have "Muscovites are always in a rush."

Comment: any idea as to the reason it is accepted? Trying to explain it to a student...